# how to mock a class used in the code

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

```
public void sendMail() {  
    /* I have simplified the method for here */
    Transport t;
    t.send();
}
```

When I am writing unit test for this, since I don't want to actually send the mail, I want to mock the `Transport` class. Is it possible and if so, how to do it ?

Comment: How are you creating the `Transport` object?  Are you using a factory which you can mock?  You might get something out of my article on the Mockito wiki, at http://code.google.com/p/mockito/wiki/MockingObjectCreation

Answer (score 0):

'cglib' may fits. 
Use ‘Enhancer' to proxy the 'Transport' class. In order not to actually sending the mail, you need pass into the 'Enhancer' a 'MethodInterceptor' which will not invoke the 'send()' method in super class.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you really want to use mockito, you can quite easily handcraft your own test double.

What you can do is create an interface that knows how to send mail:

```
public interface TransportInterface {
    public void send(Message msg);
}
```

Let the mail sending class use this interface to send the mail:

```
public class MailSender {
    private TransportInterface transport;

    public MailSender(TransportInterface transport) {
        this.transport = transport;
    }

    public void sendMail(Message msg) {
        /* This is the method from your question */
        this.transport.send(msg);
    }
}
```

In production you use an implemenation of `TransportInterface` that actually send the mail:

```
public class TransportAdapter implements TransportInterface {
    private Transport transport; // Created elsewhere...

    public void sendMail(Message msg) {
        transport.send(msg);
    }
}
```

And in your test code you can use a fake:

```
public class TransportFake implements TransportInterface {
    public void sendMail(Message msg) {
        // I don't send the mail!
    }
}
```

(It's been a while since I coded java. Hope there are not too many errors. Also, you can probably do a better job naming the classes than I have.)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use Mockito library:
here is example code:

```
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class YourTestClass{
@Mock
Transport t;

@Test
public void someTest(){
t = Mockito.mock(Transport .class);
    Mockito.when(t.send()).thenReturn(true);
}
}
```

Comment: If you use `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` and the `@Mock` annotation, you don't need to manually create the mock in your test using `Mockito.mock`. More importantly, I think the OP is asking how, for a Transport local variable created in a method, he can replace that with a mock.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which works *regardless* of how the `Transport t` object is obtained:

```
@Test
public sendMail(
    // Mocks all current and future Transport instances, 
    // including those belonging to subclasses (if any).
    @Capturing final Transport t)
{
    new SUT().sendMail();

    // Verifies that the t.send() method was called:
    new Verifications() {{ t.send(); }};
}
```

The mocking API used above is JMockit (which I develop).